# Set display picture of StoredContact from byte[]

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a `byte[]` containing picture data. I want to set this picture data as a display picture of a StoredContact in windows phone 8. I have tried:

```
byte[] data = ...

ContactStore store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite, ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.ReadOnly);
StoredContact contact = await store.FindContactByRemoteIdAsync(remoteId);
using (IInputStream stream = new MemoryStream(data).AsInputStream())
{                    
    await contact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(stream);
}
```

but i get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` on the `AsInputStream()`-call. I have the `ID_CAP_CONTACTS`-capability set and the contact belongs to a custom data store, to which i have write access. Anyone know how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

I get the data from a web request, using the following to extract the byte data:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(new PhotoObject().GetType());
var result = (PhotoObject)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(result.Data);

[DataContract]
class PhotoObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is due to something you're not showing. Where does the data come from? How are you defining your `contact`?

Comment: @MattLacey I edited to show how i get my contact from store.

Comment: and the data? as that's where the error is?

Comment: @MattLacey Sorry missed that part, added it now.

Comment: How have you verified that the stream data is correct? That seems to be the real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get around this problem. The first thing I did was to create the stream using:

```
new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length, true, true).AsInputStream();
```

instead of

```
new MemoryStream(data).AsInputStream();
```

This got rid of the `UnauthorizedException`, however it gave me an `ArgumentException: "Value does not fall within the expected range"` on the `SetDisplayPictureAsync`-call instead. I still do not know why it works, but i got around this by writing the data to temporary file, which I then open and pass to `SetDisplayPictureAsync`. This is my code for doing this:

```
//Write bytes to file then open file and pass stream to setdisplaypicture.
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var folder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Photo_Temp_Folder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("photo_" + contact.Id, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
uint written = 0;
using (var writeStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    while (written < data.Length)
    {
        written += await writeStream.WriteAsync(data.AsBuffer());
    }
}

using (var accessStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    await contact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(accessStream);
    await contact.SaveAsync();
}
await file.DeleteAsync();
```

Hope it helps someone.